# missing ; before statement in very simple script

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this statement?

```
<script>
   var startconversation{};
</script>
```

It's returning a missing ; before statement

Anyone has a hint?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Since it appears you may be new here, let me explain that StackOverflow works differently than a typical online forum.  When you post a question here, you should monitor your question for the next 20-30 minutes to see if people understood your question or asked you some clarifying questions back.  When you just post and disappear and your question isn't entirely clear and you aren't responding, your question may get downvoted or even closed and you will miss most of your opportunity for people to see your question and answer it.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

In Firefox, I get this error: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`.

In IE11, I get this error: `SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'`.

What you have is not valid Javascript.  It is a syntax error.

---

Perhaps you meant this:

```
var startconversation = {};
```

which will declare the variable `startconversation` and then initialize it to an empty object.

If you were trying to do something different, then please explain what your objective is for this line of code (e.g. what you were trying to accomplish).